# I want to download pdf from my website into my app and that pdf only show in my app only

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to download pdf from my website into my app and that pdf only show in my app only , no other app can access it. What type of logic i need to implement in my Android Code ?

Answer (score 0):

Download your pdf file into internal storage in android phone.According to the android developer site, by default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). 
Check https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files for reference.

Comment: If you find helpful answer,please accpet and close the question.